# Wait an Alamofire request finish inside other Alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I don't know if the code below is the best approach, but I need to do an Alamofire request and then iterate over the JSON objects to get the url image of each one an then save the image in my Post object array. fetchMedia returns an UIImage and inside this function there's another Alamofire request that fetch the image.

Of course the post.thumbnail is always nil because before the second request finished the post object is appended to my array.

How can I solve this?

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                    var post = Post()
                    // Fetch the title
                    if let title = subJson["title"]["rendered"].string {
                        post.title = title
                    }
                    // Fetch the the thumbnail for the cell
                    if let url = subJson["_links"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["href"].url {
                        post.thumbnail = self.fetchMedia(url: url)
                    }
                    if post.title != nil {
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                // Do something if there's an error in the response
                // Maybe load the latests posts from the database
            }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your fetchMedia request. Also if you want something to happen after fetch media request finishes, you will have to create a completion handler on fetchMedia.

Comment: First, never "wait" for anything. Just initiate the request asynchronously. Second, rather than fetching all of the images up front (known as "eager" fetch), you often will fetch images "lazily", only as required by the collection view. Third, to simplify that process, you can use [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) and you can do `cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)` and it will asynchronously retrieve the image for you.

Comment: If you want to avoid a PoD when running async requests inside async requests, have a look at GCD's `DispatchGroup`s (there are many approaches like Promises, etc.)